# xml-xsd validation debugging

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Working in xml xsd for the first time.
I have the xsd and xml data as below. When I try to validate I get error.
Code and Error below.

Please help me finding on whats going wrong.

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:t="http://www.m5net.com/mantle/configuration/connectors" targetNamespace="http://www.m5net.com/mantle/configuration/connectors" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xsd:element name="Bullhorn" type="t:Bullhorn" nillable="true" />
   <xsd:element name="Configuration" type="t:Configuration" nillable="true" />
   <xsd:element name="Lync" type="t:Lync" nillable="true" />
   <xsd:element name="SalesForce" type="t:SalesForce" nillable="true" />
   <xsd:element name="ShoreTelCosmoMobility" type="t:ShoreTelCosmoMobility" nillable="true" />
   <xsd:element name="ShoreTelCosmoScribe" type="t:ShoreTelCosmoScribe" nillable="true" />
   <xsd:element name="ShoreTelFax" type="t:ShoreTelFax" nillable="true" />
   <xsd:element name="ShoreTelMobility" type="t:ShoreTelMobility" nillable="true" />
   <xsd:element name="ShoreTelScribe" type="t:ShoreTelScribe" nillable="true" />
   <xsd:element name="ShoretelCosmoConference" type="t:ShoretelCosmoConference" nillable="true" />
   <xsd:element name="ShoretelCosmoMobility" type="t:ShoretelCosmoMobility" nillable="true" />
   <xsd:complexType name="Bullhorn">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="t:Configuration">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="AccountId" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="CorporationID" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="Password" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
               <xsd:element name="PrivateLabelID" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="UserName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="Configuration">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
            <xsd:sequence />
         </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="Lync">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="t:Configuration">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="TrustedAppComputerFQDN" type="xsd:string" />
               <xsd:element name="TrustedAppPort" type="xsd:int" />
               <xsd:element name="TrustedAppComputerGRUU" type="xsd:string" />
               <xsd:element name="CertificateFriendlyName" type="xsd:string" />
               <xsd:element name="TrustedAppEndpointOwnerURI" type="xsd:string" />
               <xsd:element name="RegistrarFQDN" type="xsd:string" />
               <xsd:element name="RegistrarPort" type="xsd:int" />
               <xsd:element name="AccountId" type="xsd:int" />
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="SalesForce">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="t:Configuration">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="IsSandbox" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="Password" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
               <xsd:element name="Token" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
               <xsd:element name="UserName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="ShoreTelCosmoMobility">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="t:Configuration">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="AccountId" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
               <xsd:element name="GroupId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="ShoreTelCosmoScribe">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="t:Configuration">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="AccountId" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
               <xsd:element name="GroupId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="ShoreTelFax">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="t:Configuration">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="AccountId" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="ConfirmReceipt" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="ConfirmSent" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="IncludeCover" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="ShoreTelMobility">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="t:Configuration">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="AccountId" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="GroupID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="ShoreTelScribe">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="t:Configuration">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="AccountId" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="PlanId" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="SendImmediate" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="SubplanId" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="ShoretelCosmoConference">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="t:Configuration">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="AccountId" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
               <xsd:element name="StartConference" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
               <xsd:element name="EndConference" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
               <xsd:element name="WebLoginMode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
               <xsd:element name="Password" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
               <xsd:element name="OutdialPrompt" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="NotifyChanges" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="NotificationEmail" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="ShoretelCosmoMobility">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="t:Configuration">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="AccountId" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
               <xsd:element name="GroupId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ShoretelCosmoConference xmlns="http://www.m5net.com/mantle/configuration/connectors" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <AccountId>13284</AccountId>
   <EndConference>Moderator leaves</EndConference>
   <NotificationEmail />
   <NotifyChanges>false</NotifyChanges>
   <OutdialPrompt>true</OutdialPrompt>
   <Password />
   <StartConference>Host Joins</StartConference>
   <WebLoginMode>Name Only</WebLoginMode>
</ShoretelCosmoConference>
```

Error :

```
XML Validation: Unexpected element(s):  
{http://www.m5net.com/mantle/configuration/connectors}NotifyChanges. Location:   
/*:ShoretelCosmoConference[1]/*:NotifyChanges[1]
```

Comment: Can you provide the XSD schema for `tns:Configuration`? I think this is the problem

Comment: @Raghav Please add the `xsd` and the `xml` code in your question, so the problem statement is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I think that the problem is in the order of the elements, as the `NotificationEmail` is a last one in your schema. Try to reorder the data, like this:</strike>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ShoretelCosmoConference xmlns="http://www.m5net.com/mantle/configuration/connectors" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <AccountId>13284</AccountId>
   <StartConference>Host Joins</StartConference>
   <EndConference>Moderator leaves</EndConference>
   <WebLoginMode>Name Only</WebLoginMode>
   <Password />
   <OutdialPrompt>true</OutdialPrompt>
   <NotifyChanges>false</NotifyChanges>
   <NotificationEmail />
</ShoretelCosmoConference>
```

I use this validation for your schema:

[W3C XML Schema (XSD) Validation online](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.VKE9DV4gAA)

And it says this error occurs:

> > Error - Line 6, 19: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 19; cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'NotifyChanges'. No child element is expected at this point.

I've rewrote the xsd-schema, and I found out that the order **does** matter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ShoretelCosmoConference xmlns="http://www.m5net.com/mantle/configuration/connectors" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <AccountId>13284</AccountId>
   <StartConference>Host Joins</StartConference>
   <EndConference>Moderator leaves</EndConference>
   <WebLoginMode>Name Only</WebLoginMode>
   <Password />
   <OutdialPrompt>true</OutdialPrompt>
   <NotifyChanges>false</NotifyChanges>
   <NotificationEmail />
</ShoretelCosmoConference>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.m5net.com/mantle/configuration/connectors" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.m5net.com/mantle/configuration/connectors">
   <xs:complexType name="ShoretelCosmoConference">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AccountId" nillable="true" type="xs:int" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="StartConference" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EndConference" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="WebLoginMode" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Password" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="OutdialPrompt" type="xs:boolean" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NotifyChanges" type="xs:boolean" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NotificationEmail" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:element name="ShoretelCosmoConference" nillable="true" type="tns:ShoretelCosmoConference" />
</xs:schema>
```

Result:

> > The XML is Well Formed and Valid.

Comment: I read in some blog that order doesnt matter. Yet, lemme give a try.
Note that error is in NotifyChanges and not NotificationEmail

Comment: @Raghav Hmmm, you are right, the order doesn't matter. May be this is because your code is `<NotificationEmail />`, not the `<NotificationEmail></NotificationEmail>`.

Comment: @Raghav don't believe everything you read in blogs. When you use `<xs:sequence>` the order of the elemenents in the xml must be in `sequence` (in the right order).